# REACT Redux profile picture not appearing

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, firebase-authentication

I have a Banner(header) that should be displaying the profile pic in an avatar after the user logs in a second time. When the user registers and it automatically logs them in the prof pic is there but when they sign out and sign back in the profile picture does not appear. My console.log said photourl was null. Here is the code snippet that renders the profile picture:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Banner.css";
import { logout } from "./features/userSlice";
import { auth } from "./firebase";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectUser } from "./features/userSlice";
import logo from "./images/logo.png";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import { Avatar } from "@mui/material";

    function Banner() {
    const user = useSelector(selectUser);
    console.log(user);
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const logoutOfApp = () => {
   dispatch(logout());
   auth.signOut();
 };

  console.log({ photoUrl: user?.photoUrl });
  return (
    <div className="banner">
     <div class="banner_container">
      <div className="banner_title">
      <h1>Hobby Hunter</h1>
      <img src={logo} alt="Hobby Hunter logo" />
    </div>
    {user ? (
      <div className="banner_right">
        <div className="header_search">
          <SearchIcon />
          <input placeholder="" type="text" />
        </div>
        <h2 className="user">Welcome {user.displayName}!</h2>
        <Avatar src={user.photoUrl}></Avatar>
        <button onClick={logoutOfApp}>Logout</button>
      </div>
       ) : null}
     </div>
   </div>
  );
}

export default Banner;

 console.log result:
 ObjectdisplayName: "daniel"email: "dd@gmail.com"uid: 
"Ojxnwbmhy6Wf3XFtsQbQmT15Ikk2"[[Prototype]]: Object
 Banner.js:20 ObjectphotoUrl: undefined[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Here is the code snippet from another component that takes in the user credentials:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "./firebase";
import "./Login.css";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { login } from "./features/userSlice";
import hpic from "./images/hpic.png";

function Login() {
 /*use state to track your user names*/
 const [name, setName] = useState("");
 const [profpic, setProfpic] = useState("");
 const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
 const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

 const loginToApp = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();

    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
       .then((userAuth) => {
         dispatch(
          login({
            email: userAuth.user.email,
            uid: userAuth.user.uid,
           displayName: userAuth.user.displayName,
            photoUrl: userAuth.user.photoURL,
          })
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error));
    };
    const register = () => {
    if (!name) {
      /*if there is no name*/
      return alert("Please enter your name!");
    }
    auth
       .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email,
        password
      ) /*creates email and password on the backend*/
      .then((userAuth) => {
        userAuth.user.updateProfile({ displayName: name }).then(() => 
  {
          dispatch(
        login({
          email: userAuth.user.email,
          uid: userAuth.user.uid,
          displayName: name,
          photoUrl: profpic,
            })
          );
       });
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error));
  };
  return (
    <div className="loginScreen">
      <form>
        <input
           value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Full name (required if registering)"
           type="text"
           />
         <input
           value={profpic}
           onChange={(e) => setProfpic(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Profile Pic (optional)"
           type="text"
          />
         <input
           value={email}
           onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
           placeholder="Email"
           type="email"
         />

          <input
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Password"
          type="password"
         />

        <button type="submit" onClick={loginToApp}>
           {" "}
          Sign In
         </button>

        <p>
         Not a member?
          <span className="login_register" onClick={register}>
            Register Now
         </span>
         </p>
      </form>
    <img src={hpic} alt="login pic" />
  </div>
  );
 }

export default Login;
```

Comment: can you also share your redux reducer ?

Comment: Technically the console log only confirms the `user` value is falsey and the ternary is returning `null`. If you care to log the `photoUrl` value then try this instead: `console.log({ photoUrl: user?.photoUrl })`. The code you've shared appears incomplete. For example, `profpic` isn't defined in the second snippet. Please [edit] to include a more complete [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese I added more

Comment: Hi does my posted answer solve your issue ?

Comment: @RohitKharche, Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

Users created with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` do not have a photo URL by default. To set the [**`photoURL`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.User#photourl), you need to update the user's profile after creating their account, as you are doing in the register function:

```
auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email,
        password
    ) /*creates email and password on the backend*/
    .then((userAuth) => {
        userAuth.user.updateProfile({ //Overriding the default user data
            displayName: name,
            photoUrl: profpic, // null by default
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch(
                login({
                    email: userAuth.user.email,
                    uid: userAuth.user.uid,
                    displayName: name,
                    photoUrl: profpic,
                })
            );
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => alert(error));
```

But in case of popUpsignIn with google provider any user who signs with this method will have profileUrl set already.

Now we can expect the profileUrl in `signInWithEmailAndPassword` as it will be set while creating the user with above code.
And if you want to set any default photUrl, if any user does not have the photoUrl initially  you can use following code to set it as placeholder:

```
auth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userAuth) => {
        dispatch(
            login({
                email: userAuth.user.email,
                uid: userAuth.user.uid,
                displayName: userAuth.user.displayName,
                photoUrl: userAuth.user.photoURL ?? ‘
                    default.png’, // any default photo if not set
            })
        );
    })
    .catch((error) => alert(error));
```

For more information go through [createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword)